# unable to deploy github repo with npm run deploy

Tags: reactjs, git, github, npm, deployment

im trying to build and deploy my github repo but whenever i run `npm run deploy` i get this error how do i fix this

```
> animate-on-scroll@0.0.0 predeploy
> npm run build


> animate-on-scroll@0.0.0 build
> vite build

vite v5.1.1 building for production...
✓ 326 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                   0.46 kB │ gzip:  0.30 kB
dist/assets/index-BwZMlJHq.css    0.22 kB │ gzip:  0.17 kB
dist/assets/index-CdR2BujV.js   242.26 kB │ gzip: 79.28 kB
✓ built in 2.99s

> animate-on-scroll@0.0.0 deploy
> gh-pages -d build

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\lstop\OneDrive\Documents\JavaScript Html and Css\JavaScript\Website\AnimateOnScroll\animate-on-scroll\build'
    at Object.statSync (node:fs:1660:25)
    at Object.statSync (C:\Users\lstop\OneDrive\Documents\JavaScript Html and Css\JavaScript\Website\AnimateOnScroll\animate-on-scroll\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:319:16)
    at Object.publish (C:\Users\lstop\OneDrive\Documents\JavaScript Html and Css\JavaScript\Website\AnimateOnScroll\animate-on-scroll\node_modules\gh-pages\lib\index.js:90:13)
    at C:\Users\lstop\OneDrive\Documents\JavaScript Html and Css\JavaScript\Website\AnimateOnScroll\animate-on-scroll\node_modules\gh-pages\bin\gh-pages.js:12:13
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at publish (C:\Users\lstop\OneDrive\Documents\JavaScript Html and Css\JavaScript\Website\AnimateOnScroll\animate-on-scroll\node_modules\gh-pages\bin\gh-pages.js:10:10) 
    at C:\Users\lstop\OneDrive\Documents\JavaScript Html and Css\JavaScript\Website\AnimateOnScroll\animate-on-scroll\node_modules\gh-pages\bin\gh-pages.js:140:12
```

ive got everything set up correctly 'i think' so im not sure why there is an error

it now says that it doesnt recognise the `gh-pages` command even though i have ran `npm install --save gh-pages` and it is in the dependencies part of my `package.json` folder and i have

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

in my `package.json` but when i try to just run `gh-pages -d build` it comes up with this

```
gh-pages : The term 'gh-pages' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gh-pages -d build
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gh-pages:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

*Considering the only information given...*

### The error message indicates that the `gh-pages` module is unable to find the directory it needs to deploy (build directory). This could be due to several reasons:

1. **Incorrect build directory path**: Make sure that the path to your
   build directory is correctly specified in your `gh-pages`
   configuration. Double-check your package.json file or any other
   configuration files where the build directory path might be
   specified.
2. **Build script not generating the build directory**: Ensure that your
   build script (npm run build) is generating the build
   directory with the necessary files. Sometimes, if the build process
   fails or if there's a misconfiguration, the build directory might
   not be created or populated properly.
3. **Permissions issue:** Check if your user has the necessary permissions
   to access and write to the directory where the build is supposed to
   be created. It seems you're deploying from a directory under
   OneDrive, which sometimes can have sync or permission issues.
4. **Filesystem case sensitivity**: Ensure that the case of your directory
   names matches exactly what's expected. Filesystems on different
   operating systems can be case-sensitive, and a mismatch in the case
   of directory names can cause issues.
5. **Dependency issue**: Sometimes, there could be issues with the
   dependencies or the version of `gh-pages` you're using. Try updating
   gh-pages to the latest version or reinstalling dependencies (npm
   install).

*Check these points to see if any of them resolve your issue. If not, providing more details about your project setup and configuration could help diagnose the problem further.*

Comment: @KyleXyianDilebeck it says i dont have the gh-pages module

Comment: have you tried to uninstall this module and reinstall globally instead? ( npm -g )